# AngularJS : Is it necessary to bind all my controller methods to $scope

Tags: angularjs, methods, scope, method-declaration

When do we need to bind an method to $scope in controller,i am dealing with methods which is just mapping operation on object.

```
Example :
$scope.myVar = {};

     function myMyObject(x) {
          $scope.myVar = {
                  "xKey":x
           }

     }

    to 

    $scope.myMyObject = function(x) {
          $scope.myVar = {
                  "xKey":x
           }

     }

    myMyObject(10);
    $scope.myMyObject(10);
```

> ```
> Is it necessary to bind $scope to myMyObject method here ?
> ```

Comment: no. you need to use $scope only for the methods called or need to be called from view.

Comment: No, its not nessesery. You can bind to `this` and use `controllerAs` syntax in the view - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind methods to `$scope` only when they will need to be called from the View. If they are just private methods that you only call from the controller itself, there's no need to pollute the scope.

In your specific scenario, there is no need to bind `myMyoObject()` to the scope.

**Edit:** You can avoid using $scope altogether and use controllerAs syntax, in which case instead of binding to $scope, you bind to this. The non-public functions still will be kept unbound to anything.

Comment: You can add methods and variables to `this` and that will be visible in views too.

Comment: @Niezbor True if you want to use `controllerAs` syntax.

Comment: @Omri Aharon : if the same method i want to access in directive do i need to bind it to scope right ?

Comment: @SidBhalke Yes, because for the directive to know about it you need it to be exposed via the scope, or controllerAs syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Only methods defined on  $scope object are accessible from the HTML/view. Example from ng-click, filters, etc.
-If your method is not required to be accessed from html , then there is no need to bind it to $scope.

Comment: how about directives ?

Comment: @SidBhalke Directives are always visible because of the name.

Comment: @456: how to about accessing scope methods from controller to directive ?

Comment: using isolated scope and '&' parameter, you can access the controller method in directive

Answer (score 1):

As a good practice, you can declare all your functions in your controller and then bind to the $scope only the functions you need.

Example:

```
function _myHelperFunction(param) {
    //do some stuff
}

function myFunction(otherParam) {
    //do some stuff or use the _myHelperFunction
}

function myFunction2(otherParam) {
    //do some stuff or use the _myHelperFunction
}

function myFunction3(otherParam) {
    //do some stuff or use the _myHelperFunction
}

$scope.myFunction = myFunction
$scope.myFunction2 = myFunction2
$scope.myFunction3 = myFunction3
```

Or even better with ES6 destructuring

```
[$scope.myFunction, $scope.myFunction2, $scope.myFunction3] =
[myFunction, myFunction2, myFunction3]
```

Or:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    myFunction,
    myFunction2,
    myFunction3
})
```

Comment: Perfect :) I liked this approach clean and neat.

Answer (score 0):

Keep independent function in the controller itself.

Adding all functions to the  $scope will effect the application performance in long run and in complex apps with large functions

write function in $scope only if you want to access it in the html(view/partial) or in child $scopes

function written in parent $scope is accessible for the child $scopes